# Perl - skipping second if in a foreach loop

Tags: perl, if-statement, foreach

If i have 2 `if` loops in a Perl `foreach` loop, how can I skip the second `if` if my script enters my first `if`?

Example:

```
my $var1 = 1;
my $var2 = 1;

for my $item ('...') {
    if ( $var1 == 1 ) {
        print "First IF \n";
    }
    if ( $var2 == 1 ) {
        print "Second IF (I don't want this to be printed if the first if is true)\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using `$a` and `$b` variables, they are used in `sort` function.

Comment: Also it would be good to avoid barewords when meaning variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an [`elsif`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements):

```
if (pred1) {
    ...
} elsif (pred2) {
    ...
}
```

Predicate 2 and the block [NB: not "loop"] associated with it won't be considered if Predicate 1 evaluates to `true`.

Comment: @ZeldaElf NB: `if ($a == 1)` - not just `a`

Comment: @mpapec You're nitpicking on my indentation?!  Stuff that...  Every C-braced language I use I indent that way, and I'm not changing it for Perl just because one author says so!

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set up the logic so that test 2 is only checked if test 1 is false.

```
foreach my $item (@items) {
  if (test1) {
    ...
  elsif (test2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But another option would be to use `next` to skip directly to the next iteration of your loop.

```
foreach my $item (@items) {
  if (test1) {
    ...
    next;
  }
  if (test2) {
    ...
  }
}
```